# scale images in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have an image like this:

```css
div.sliderimg {
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 5000ms linear 0s;
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sliderimg" style="background-image: url('http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=2400')">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <small>FEATURED ARTICLE</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

but it couldn't run. can please help me.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36948/)

Comment: If you refresh the page, everything starts over again.

Comment: @zer00ne  I want something like this:https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kvZm3

Comment: It's all in the snippet, just apply that to your code.

Comment: I know. my code is a bit different. It use img tag but I use style...

Comment: Just an image no carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if transitions occur on document load. I would use an animation instead:

```
@keyframes example {
  from {transform: scale(1, 1)}
  to {transform: scale(1.05, 1.05)}
}

div.sliderimg {
  animation-name:example;
  animation-duration:5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you linked jQuery to your document, then you can use it to add a class onload. `transition` CSS will do its job from here.

I suggest to use background-size instead transform:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sliderimg").addClass("loaded");
});
```

```css
div.sliderimg {
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 5000ms linear 1s;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.loaded {
  background-size: 105% auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderimg" style="background-image: url('http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1419064642531-e575728395f2?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=800&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=2400')">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <small>FEATURED ARTICLE</small>
  </div>
</div>
```